# Python: .group "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'"

Tags: python, for-loop, python-re

When i put the .group() inside the "FOR" loops I get an error.

```
import re

with open(r'C:\Users\testuser\OneDrive - personal\Network\network.log', 'r+') as LOG:
    OUTPUT = LOG.readlines()

    for LINE in OUTPUT:
        x = re.search(r'\s+name ".*"', LINE).group()
        print(x)
```

```
 x = re.search(r'\s+name ".*"', LINE).group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

However if i simply delete **".group()"** the script executes as expected. However I don't wish for the value **None** or **<re.Match object; span=(0, 30), match='    name "Default Access Rule"'>
**
I just want the the value that matches the pattern to be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if there are no matches in some lines.

```py
import re

with open(r'C:\Users\testuser\OneDrive - personal\Network\network.log', 'r+') as LOG:
    OUTPUT = LOG.readlines()

    for LINE in OUTPUT:
        x = re.search(r'\s+name ".*"', LINE)
        if x is not None:
            print(f'Got match: {x.group()}')

        # Otherwise there is not match in the line.
```